# "search" a string in "when:" conditional statement?

Tags: ansible

In the following playbook, I have to use `search` in a `when:` statement. Can you please tell me what is wrong with the statement `when: item.name is search (domain_list)`? `domain_lis`t is an array variable defined in `files.yml` as shown below.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  connection: local
  vars_files:
    - files.yml
  vars:
    infra:
      - name: ironman.vcloud-lab.com
        connection_state: CONNECTED
      - name: hulk.vcloud-lab.com
        connection_state: CONNECTED
      - name: captain.vcloud-lab.com
        connection_state: DISCONNECTED
      - name: hawkeye.vcloud-lab.com
        connection_state: DISCONNECTED

  tasks:
  - name: Filter list of only connected esxi
    set_fact:
      esxilist: "{{esxilist | default([]) + [item]}}"
    with_items: "{{infra}}"
    when: item.name is search (domain_list) ## <= please correct me here, it doesn't work

  - name: Show connected esxi list information
    debug:
      var: esxilist
```

files.yml

```yaml
---
domain_list:
  - ironman
  - captain
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the short name and test the presence in the list. For example, use *regex_replace*

```yaml
  - name: Filter list of only connected esxi
    set_fact:
      esxilist: "{{ esxilist|default([]) + [item] }}"
    loop: "{{ infra }}"
    when: _short in domain_list
    vars:
      _short: "{{ item.name|regex_replace('^(.*?)\\.(.*)$', '\\1') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  esxilist:
  - connection_state: CONNECTED
    name: ironman.vcloud-lab.com
  - connection_state: DISCONNECTED
    name: captain.vcloud-lab.com
```

---

The next option is to *split* the string and select the first item. For example

```yaml
    vars:
      _short: "{{ item.name.split('.')|first }}"
```

gives the same result.

---

See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    domain_list: [a, b]
    infra:
      - {name: a.vcloud-lab.com, state: CONNECTED}
      - {name: b.vcloud-lab.com, state: DISCONNECTED}
      - {name: c.vcloud-lab.com, state: CONNECTED}
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      l1: "{{ l1|default([]) + [item] }}"
    with_items: "{{ infra }}"
    when: _short in domain_list
    vars:
      _short: "{{ item.name.split('.')|first }}"
  - debug:
      var: l1
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! However, it didn't work in a similar playbook but more complicated dict. What changes should I make here: https://pastebin.com/yQ7SjLFs

```
please see the task "-set fact:" there.
Thank you again!

Comment: Please see the first element of the dict,https://pastebin.com/SG5CfbpF

```
I tried:     _short: "{{ my_ontap.ontap_info.volume_info[item].split(':')|first }}"
but, it is not working. "AWS_logs" is the value of "volume_list", for instance

Comment: Analyzing your complex code is time-consuming. Sorry. Open a new question and make it [mre]. It's your job to remove the irrelevant code and data.

Comment: Yes. I already tried and used a simplified code at beginning. but, the real code / dict is more complicated. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. The point is to remove irrelevant code and make it [mre]. I've added an example of what it means in practice.

Comment: @vkky2k moreover please do not multiply the questions on the same subject as the same kind of conversion already happened on you [latest one](/questions/67236183). At the very least, delete the other one if this one is more accurate, the best scenario on SO being to edit your question to reflect your exact problem.

Comment: @VladimirBotka Is there any way I can print out the value of _short? I couldn't